# Issue in using dialog in Touch UI of AEM 6.2

Tags: aem

I am working on AEM 6.2. I am creating a dialog (cq:dialog) for touch UI. After creating a page i am not able to see my component in the design mode of the touch UI while trying to enable it and thus the dialog not enabled. Tried creating a simple dialog (using create->dialog) for classic UI for the same component and now i can see my component along with its dialog in touch UI of the page. Is it mandatory to create dialog for both views (Touch & Classic) to get the dialog enabled and working on both UI's?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not mandatory to create a dialog node. However, some node is required indicating it is an editable component.

If you want to see your component in design view then you can create either of the nodes:

1. cq:editConfig [cq:EditConfig]
2. dialog
3. design_dialog

So in your case if you dont want a dialog node you can work with editConfig.